# Cordova Login with Facebook causes a blank page

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, iframe

I have created a cordova app which has an iframe and shows an external web page. (fasteat.biz) - The iFrame works perfectly when I build the app in Android/iOS, you can browse the whole website, register, login, etc.

However, an issue I am having, is that they have a facebook login on the webpage, which works when logging in on their website, and it also works when I am viewing the app through my computer browser (via the iFrame). On the app when I click login with Facebook it just sends me to a white blank page. I have no clue as to why this is happening and I was hoping to get some help.

I have attached my code of the app below:

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>FastEat</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://fasteat.biz/home"></iframe>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

iframe {
    min-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Do I need to add a cordova plugin to handle the Facebook login? I hope someone can help, thank you.